# removeEventListener and anonymous function with arguments

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a text input where I add a event listener.
This event listener execute a anonymous function by `onkeyup`.
This anonymous function contains a foo function.
This foo function have an argument `number` for displaying number in console.

And I have a button for removing the event listener added.
But when I click this button and type in the text input, the event listener is not removed, so the foo function displays number again in the console.

Here is the code, very simple :

```
<input type="text" value="" id="input_text">

<input type="button" value="Remove Event Listener" onclick="deleteEventListener();">

<script type="text/javascript">

number = 0;

//Function to display number in console :
function foo(arg_number)
{
    number = arg_number+1;
    
    console.log(number);    
}

//The text input :
input_text = document.getElementById("input_text");

//Add event listener to the text input :
input_text.addEventListener("keyup", function(){foo(number);}, false);

//Function to remove event listener :
function deleteEventListener()
{
    input_text.removeEventListener("keyup", function(){foo(number);}, false);   
}
```

You can try it :https://jsfiddle.net/5LtmLzqy/

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your function an external function.

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp):

> Note: To remove event handlers, the function specified with the addEventListener() method must be an external function, like in the example above (myFunction).
>
> Anonymous functions, like `element.removeEventListener("event", function(){ myScript });` will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can make my anonymous an external function ?

Comment: Put `function foonumber(){foo(number);}` after the function foo.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a smart solution ! solved thank to you.

Comment: But you didn't specify how to pass arguments to it then. He said "with arguments"

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved through `arguments.callee`, store value of `arguments.callee` in a globally scoped javascript variable and pass this value as an argument of `removeEventListener()`.

```
   number = 0;
    var myAnonymous = null;
    //Function to display number in console :
    function foo(arg_number) {
        number = arg_number + 1;
        console.log(number);
    }

    //The text input :
    input_text = document.getElementById("input_text");

    //Add event listener to the text input :
    input_text.addEventListener("keyup", function () { myAnonymous = arguments.callee; foo(number); }, false);

    //Function to remove event listener :
    function deleteEventListener() {
        if (myAnonymous != null)
            input_text.removeEventListener("keyup", myAnonymous);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much with arguments.callee !